# How many words of length $4$ can be formed by the following language $S =\{ a, bb\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Of course, I can list all of the different words

- $aaaa$
- $aabb$
- $abba$
- $bbaa$
- $bbbb$

and then count them. But I would like to find the answer in a more mathematical way, perhaps through combinatorics. Any help?

Comment: Are you saying any 4 letters from the entire alphabet put together?

Comment: Hmm, I think what I should have written is that S is an alphabet consisting of two 'letters': "a" and "bb." It just so happens that one of these letters has length 2 (i.e., "bb"). So I the question is asking how many words of length 4 can be made from this alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any word length $n$, we can have anywhere between $0$ and $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ occurrences of $bb$. If we have, say, $B$ of them, then the number of distinct ways to order $B$ $bb$'s and $n-2B$ $a's$ is
$${{B + (n - 2B)}\choose{B}} = {{n - B}\choose{B}}.$$

Summing over the possible numbers $B$ of occurrences of $bb$ gives
$$\sum_{B = 0}^{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor} {{n - B}\choose{B}}.$$

This turns out be nothing more than the $n$th Fibonacci number $F_n$ (where we take $F_0 = F_1 = 1$). See, e.g., http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle.html .

For $n = 4$ the sum is
$${{4}\choose{0}} + {{3}\choose{1}} + {{2}\choose{2}} = 1 + 3 + 1 = 5,$$
which agrees with your count. These terms respectively correspond with the sets $\{aaaa\}, \{aabb, abba, bbaa\}, \{bbbb\}$.

Comment: Brilliant, Travis. Does your formula hold for odd n as well?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, in fact that's exactly why the upper bound on the sum is the floor of $\frac{n}{2}$ rather than $\frac{n}{2}$ itself. Note that I edited my answer to show that the sum is nothing other than the $n$th Fibonacci number $F_n$---this is essentially because the sum is by definition the sum over the $n$th "shallow diagonal" in Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Great! I also wonder if you might give some criticism of how I approached this question on my own. I learned how to solve combinatoric problems such as these in a very particular way, a way that I find quite intuitive. I consider each letter in the word of length n as a kind of slot. I then think about how many letters can be chosen for each slot and use the addition and multiplication rules to find the total number of words of length n... (con't)

Comment: So, for example, in the case of 1 bb and 2 a's: C(4-1,1)*C(1,1)*C(1,1) = C(3,1)* 1* 1 = 3. The first binomial coefficient actually represents two slots since the b's come in pairs. The latter two slots are for the a's. My thinking there is that there is one way to choose an a for this slot.

Comment: Can you offer a critique of this thought process? I also cannot think of a rigorous way to explain why I am subtracting 4 by 1 in the first "slot." My informal reasoning is that an extra b is tagging along in the pair, so I have to account for that and subtract 1.

Comment: Can you explain why you form a product of the $C(n, k)$'s to count the number of words with a given count of $a$'s and $bb$'s?

Comment: Isn't just a simple application of the multiplication rule? Each C(n,k) represents the number of ways the letters can be chosen for a slot, and multiplying each of these C(n,k)'s gets me the total number of words.

Comment: Of course, I could be horribly wrong!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but I don't see what "represents the number of ways that the letters can be chosen for a slot" means so that it is $3$ for the $bb$ term but $1$ for the $a$ terms. In my count, I treat each of the B $bb$'s and $n-2B$ $a$'s as a single object, and so there are $(n - 2B) + B = n - B$ objects and thus $(n - B)!$ ways to order them. Since the $a$'s are indistinguishable and there are $(n - 2B)!$ ways to order them, and likewise $B!$ ways to order the $bb$'s, there are $\frac{(n-B)!}{B!(n - 2B!)} = {{n - B}\choose{B}}$ distinct words with $B$ $bb$'s and $n - 2B$ $a$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show this is to let

$\;\;\;c_n$ be the number of words of length n,

$\;\;\;a_n$ be the number of words of length n ending with "a", and

$\;\;\;b_n$ be the number of words of length n ending with "bb".

Then $c_n=a_n+b_n$ where $a_n=c_{n-1}$ and $b_n=c_{n-2}$;

so we have $c_n=c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$ with $c_1=1$ and $c_2=2$.  Thus $(c_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence.